# On mouse over and on mouse out

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

how do i write a function that uses  getElementById to change the picture in that image to something new (picture2.jpg). then  second function that changes the picture in that image back to the first picture (picture1.jpg).How do i then modify the image on the page so that when you run your mouse over it?

Am i at least headed in the right direction?

function getpic
var pic = ("picture2.jpg)
{
if onmouseover(picture2.jpg)

else if onmouseout (picture1.jpg)
}

Comment: Pretty good documentation on [mouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [mouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) addressing a very similar problem in their sample code.

Comment: This is quite trival, have you tried doing this? If so show us your code. This isn't a "we write code for you" site, it's Q&A about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```js
var link = document.getElementById('img');

function chngImg(){
  link.src = "http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg";
  }

function chngImg2(){
  link.src = "http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"
  }
```

```html
<img id="img" onmouseover="chngImg()" onmouseout="chngImg2()" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
```

If you need explanation, let me know.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I think I just kept trying to mix two things together that didn't necessarily go,and then left out half of it... but do I have to use "chngImg" or could I use any function name?

Comment: Use anything.  Whatever you want is fine.  Just make sure that you don't use a reserved keyword.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp